# How to turn on and off Predictive text option of keyboard Programmatically

Tags: android

I just want to turn on Predictive text option when activity created and off when activity destroy

Answer (score 4):

I think predictive text input is a parameter of a input object. So when you invoke an input object when starting to edit a text, you can give it a parameter : `text|textNoSuggestions`, so the keyboard will not display the suggestions.

```
setInputType(text|textNoSuggestions)
```

Comment: exactly i want to turn off in facebook api login activity and i want to change keyboard setting option