# disable predictive text on webview

Tags: android, android-webview, facebook-android-sdk

I have integrated Facebook in my apps and its working fine, but one issue occur. If predictive textinput is on, then password is shown in suggestion . So is that any way  to disable predictive text on webview in Facebook api

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in the Facebook SDK you can modify to stop the autosuggestion. Open the `FbDialog` class in the SDK and look for the `setUpWebView` method.

```
private void setUpWebView(int margin) {
    LinearLayout webViewContainer = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    this.mWebView = new WebView(getContext());
    this.mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    this.mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    this.mWebView.setWebViewClient(new FbWebViewClient(null));
    this.mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    this.mWebView.loadUrl(this.mUrl);
    this.mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);
    this.mWebView.setVisibility(4);
    this.mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);

    webViewContainer.setPadding(margin, margin, margin, margin);
    webViewContainer.addView(this.mWebView);
    this.mContent.addView(webViewContainer);
  }
```

And add these lines anywhere before the `addView` line:

```
this.mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
this.mWebView.clearFormData();
```

Comment: thanks for reply , but I want to stop predictive text while inserting text fill up on password not to stop auto suggestion

Comment: Try to play with what comes up via Intellisense (or it's Java equivalent) and see if there is a setInputType(textNoSuggestions) setting, as suggested here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659846/how-to-trun-on-and-off-predictive-text-option-of-keyboard-programmatically)

Comment: Please see on screen shot in which show predictive text on password like CDN, CAN as more and i want to disable this through code ..?